# Update panel blinking after F5 (Refresh)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've an update panel on page, when I click F5 to refresh the page the items in it starting to blink. 
What could be the problem ? Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give us a better description of the problem and some code.

Comment: thanks @jrummell the problem is solved. I guess no more any code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I was running my application locally in Chrome. It seems that it would only do it when I was running it locally and stopped completely once it had been published. Try publishing your application and see if it fixes it.

Comment: thanks. I think I've the same problem too, I haven't test it but I was thinking about it too..